# how to hide HTML button selection?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to hide HTML Button selection like in above image whenever i click on buttons from 1 to 25 Its shows that it is selected like now **i hv clicked on 10 its shows dotted border when i click on 10 no button ..** I want to hide this for security purpose how can i do this any idea will help me

Comment: Explain the security aspect. Simply hiding via CSS will not address the issue.

Comment: Out of topic: add Screegrab! the firefox plugin for screenshots, it's perfect!

Comment: @stillstanding - given the context, my guess would be for visual security rather than phyical security; ie so that someone standing behind you gets fewer clues as to which buttons you're pressing. Maybe he's writing a kiosk app?

Comment: the phrase "when i click on 10 `no button`" doesn't seem to be congruent with security at all

Comment: @all my security aspect is .. I'm going to store the values of button and i want to overcum the shoulder surfing(hidden camera) prb while clicking on button .. i want to hide the selection of button ... the dotted outline.. bt it seems not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It usually isn't a good idea to remove the line for accessibility reasons. But if you really want to, some CSS like the following should work:

```
outline : 0;
-moz-outline : 0;
border : 0
```

These should be set on the `:active` and `:focus` psuedo classes for the buttons

Comment: outline only, I'd have thought; you probably don't want to change the border, since that is there to start with and the requirement is for the button to remain the same.

Comment: I tried this CSS property bt its not working in my case can any one give me online demo . for this CSS property.

Comment: /*for FireFox*/
    input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner
    {   
        border : 0px;
    } 
/*for IE8 */
    input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus
    {     
        outline : none; 
    }

Answer (score 2):

in css

```
outline : none;
-moz-outline : none;
```

applied to the button or button:focus

Comment: @fcalderan can u give me any example .. working example of this property

Answer (score 1):

```
/*for FireFox*/


 input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner 
{
 border : 0px; 
} 


/*for IE8 */ 

input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus
{
 outline : none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the css set outline:none;

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css rule, or add an inline style like:

```
<button style="outline:none">1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

css: `outline:0;`

you are triggering :focus, or the :active pseudo state which has the default dotted outline.